# HTML2Canvas take screenshot before page loads even with "window.onload" function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to take a screenshot from my page, and that's ok, but it takes the shot before the whole page loads.

My pages has two API's, and some images, but the html2canvas take the shot before it loads.

Look my code:

```
function getScreen(){
    html2canvas(document.body, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        }
    }); 
}
document.body.addEventListener("onload", getScreen());
```

I already tried with "ready" function, and with "window.load". I tried "setTimeout" too, but all cases the shot came without the apis and images. I put the code in the final, before close the body in HTML.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line :

`document.body.addEventListener("onload", getScreen());`

To :

`document.addEventListener("ready", getScreen);`

In the first line, you're calling the `getScreen` function and passing its return value as the event listener, while you give the function reference in the second line.

Comment: The problem now is that the canvas even  appears, like the page never "loads".

Comment: @JhonataGalante Edited my answer

Comment: It keeps on. I tried the setTimeout, that following your tip, it worked. But the screenshot of the html2canvas is not taking the API's and images, even next it loads.

Comment: Ok, so I guess you're doing ajax calls, maybe you should call `getScreen` after you loaded all the images, ie. after your ajax calls ?

Comment: http://i1069.photobucket.com/albums/u478/JhonGalante/img2_zpstxgvvsy8.jpg

http://i1069.photobucket.com/albums/u478/JhonGalante/img1_zpsjszirzsm.jpg

Look, the api appears, but not complete.

Comment: You have to call `getScreen` after your API's calls. You should have promises/callbacks available to know when it finished loading.

Comment: I just insert those options in the html2canvas call, 
               "allowTaint: true,
          useCORS: true,
          taintTest: false,"
and it works!

Comment: Glad you found a way :)